# Adobe Illustrator Svg Issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-after-effects

I am trying to import an svg into illustrator solely to make a file conversion so that I can use the vector in after effects.
Here is the preview of the svg:

[image]

Here is what it appears as when I import into illustrator

[image]

Some of those characters are cut off, I thought maybe it has something to do with too much geometry to properly display the vector. I also tried importing the expression as a png directly into after effects, however the resolution was not ideal (compared to using the vector form).

If there is a better way to do this file conversion or a fix to illustrator's problem, I would greatly appreciate a reply. I am using LaTeX to generate these by the way if that is in some way pertinent to the problem.

https://svgshare.com/i/ZiP.svg Here is the svg I used, sorry its late

I am a beginner in both these programs, I apologize if these questions have a simple fix or if I am wasting your time, I have tried many things before coming here. Thank you for reading, all answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: Does the SVG display properly in a browser? Can you share the SVG on svgshare.com?

Comment: I am sorry I tried using svgshare but it threw an error message "Over Quota
This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later." I tried again today but it was showing the same error.

Comment: You can try if you want some direct tools that export, directly, from `LaTeX` (The tools used `MathJaX` rendering a subset of `LaTeX`) to `SVG`. You try to see if they work better. 1. https://viereck.ch/latex-to-svg/ 2. https://www.geogebra.org/m/j8bx2s9x 3. http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php 4. http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/

Comment: Well, the svg code you have is certainly a bit suspect. Why would there be a M after a Z? Which is probably causing this. Try clearing fills and only look at strokes you should see this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going in the outline view (Ctrl/Command + Y) should help find & fix the issue. In this case there are some clipping masks that need to be deleted.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The SVG doesn't load properly in Illustrator, it's all messed up. I get a different problem from you. Everything is visible but the letters are jumbled up and overlap each other.

[image]

The SVG works fine in Inkscape though, which is generally a bit more forgiving than Illy. As far as I can tell, the problem appears to be caused by the use of multiple clones, or quite possibly as @joojaa has noticed, some malformed path data, perhaps a combination of the two. The SVG code is a bit of a mess TBH.

So, here's a fix, a bit of cleaning up in Inskcape:

Open in Inksape, do *Edit > Clone > Unlink clones recursively*, then do *Path > Stroke to Path* on the two horizontal lines to convert them to paths. I also see an awful lot of nested groups. You could Ungroup everything several times to remove most of those. Then do *File > Clean up document*. Finally Save as an Optimised SVG.

Anyway I tested this, seems to work OK in Illustrator after fixing in Inkscape. Here's the SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="19pt" height="34pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 19 34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <g>
   <path d="m0.674 32.2h2.95v-0.625h-2.33v-28.7h2.33v-0.625h-2.95z"/>
   <path d="m8.61 3.25c-0.0938-0.406-0.406-0.812-1.06-0.812-0.984 0-1.78 0.719-2.03 1.36-0.0469 0.109-0.141 0.391-0.141 0.672 0 0.484 0.375 1.28 1.45 1.28 1.81 0 2.55-2.25 2.55-3.23 0-1.2-0.781-1.88-1.72-1.88-1.14 0-1.45 0.906-1.45 1.11 0 0.0625 0.0469 0.25 0.281 0.25 0.25 0 0.391-0.203 0.391-0.375 0-0.188-0.141-0.25-0.266-0.266 0.344-0.531 0.922-0.531 1.03-0.531 0.531 0 1.14 0.328 1.14 1.33 0 0.297-0.0312 0.547-0.156 1.09zm-1.77 2.28c-0.781 0-0.875-0.594-0.875-0.812 0-0.266 0.188-0.953 0.266-1.12 0.125-0.328 0.547-0.969 1.34-0.969 0.672 0 0.891 0.531 0.891 0.953 0 0.469-0.453 1.95-1.62 1.95z"/>
   <path d="m12.5 2.86h0.672c0.141 0 0.234 0 0.234-0.156 0-0.0938-0.0938-0.0938-0.219-0.0938h-0.641c0.156-0.891 0.203-1.2 0.266-1.41 0.0312-0.156 0.188-0.297 0.359-0.297 0 0 0.188 0 0.328 0.0781-0.297 0.0938-0.312 0.344-0.312 0.375 0 0.156 0.125 0.266 0.281 0.266 0.188 0 0.391-0.156 0.391-0.422 0-0.328-0.328-0.5-0.688-0.5-0.312 0-0.656 0.172-0.844 0.516-0.141 0.266-0.188 0.578-0.344 1.39h-0.547c-0.141 0-0.234 0-0.234 0.156 0 0.0938 0.0938 0.0938 0.219 0.0938h0.516c0 0.0469-0.438 2.55-0.609 3.3-0.0312 0.156-0.156 0.672-0.484 0.672-0.0156 0-0.172 0-0.312-0.0781 0.281-0.0938 0.312-0.344 0.312-0.375 0-0.156-0.125-0.266-0.281-0.266-0.188 0-0.391 0.156-0.391 0.422 0 0.312 0.328 0.5 0.672 0.5 0.438 0 0.75-0.453 0.828-0.609 0.25-0.469 0.422-1.33 0.438-1.41z"/>
  </g>
  <path d="m4.95 7.76v-0.405h9.35v0.405z" color="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width=".1" style="-inkscape-stroke:none"/>
  <g>
   <path d="m8.68 11.1c-0.0938-0.406-0.406-0.812-1.06-0.812-0.984 0-1.78 0.719-2.03 1.36-0.0469 0.109-0.141 0.391-0.141 0.672 0 0.484 0.375 1.28 1.45 1.28 1.81 0 2.55-2.25 2.55-3.23 0-1.2-0.781-1.88-1.72-1.88-1.14 0-1.45 0.906-1.45 1.11 0 0.0625 0.0469 0.25 0.281 0.25 0.25 0 0.391-0.203 0.391-0.375 0-0.188-0.141-0.25-0.266-0.266 0.344-0.531 0.922-0.531 1.03-0.531 0.531 0 1.14 0.328 1.14 1.33 0 0.297-0.0312 0.547-0.156 1.09zm-1.77 2.28c-0.781 0-0.875-0.594-0.875-0.812 0-0.266 0.188-0.953 0.266-1.12 0.125-0.328 0.547-0.969 1.34-0.969 0.672 0 0.891 0.531 0.891 0.953 0 0.469-0.453 1.95-1.62 1.95z"/>
   <path d="m11.4 12.7c-0.0625 0.234-0.297 0.609-0.656 0.609-0.0156 0-0.234 0-0.375-0.0938 0.281-0.0938 0.312-0.344 0.312-0.391 0-0.156-0.125-0.25-0.281-0.25-0.203 0-0.406 0.156-0.406 0.422 0 0.344 0.391 0.5 0.734 0.5 0.328 0 0.609-0.188 0.781-0.484 0.172 0.359 0.547 0.484 0.828 0.484 0.812 0 1.23-0.859 1.23-1.06 0-0.0938-0.0938-0.0938-0.109-0.0938-0.109 0-0.109 0.0469-0.141 0.125-0.141 0.484-0.562 0.844-0.953 0.844-0.281 0-0.422-0.188-0.422-0.453 0-0.188 0.172-0.812 0.359-1.59 0.141-0.531 0.453-0.703 0.688-0.703 0.0156 0 0.219 0 0.375 0.0938-0.219 0.0625-0.312 0.266-0.312 0.391 0 0.141 0.125 0.25 0.281 0.25s0.391-0.125 0.391-0.422c0-0.391-0.453-0.516-0.719-0.516-0.359 0-0.641 0.234-0.781 0.5-0.125-0.281-0.453-0.5-0.844-0.5-0.781 0-1.22 0.859-1.22 1.08 0 0.0781 0.0938 0.0781 0.109 0.0781 0.0938 0 0.0938-0.0156 0.141-0.109 0.172-0.547 0.609-0.844 0.953-0.844 0.234 0 0.422 0.125 0.422 0.453 0 0.141-0.0938 0.484-0.156 0.734z"/>
   <path d="m8.61 22.1c-0.0938-0.406-0.406-0.812-1.06-0.812-0.984 0-1.78 0.719-2.03 1.36-0.0469 0.109-0.141 0.391-0.141 0.672 0 0.484 0.375 1.28 1.45 1.28 1.81 0 2.55-2.25 2.55-3.23 0-1.2-0.781-1.88-1.72-1.88-1.14 0-1.45 0.906-1.45 1.11 0 0.0625 0.0469 0.25 0.281 0.25 0.25 0 0.391-0.203 0.391-0.375 0-0.188-0.141-0.25-0.266-0.266 0.344-0.531 0.922-0.531 1.03-0.531 0.531 0 1.14 0.328 1.14 1.33 0 0.297-0.0312 0.547-0.156 1.09zm-1.77 2.28c-0.781 0-0.875-0.594-0.875-0.812 0-0.266 0.188-0.953 0.266-1.12 0.125-0.328 0.547-0.969 1.34-0.969 0.672 0 0.891 0.531 0.891 0.953 0 0.469-0.453 1.95-1.62 1.95z"/>
   <path d="m12.5 21.7h0.672c0.141 0 0.234 0 0.234-0.156 0-0.0938-0.0938-0.0938-0.219-0.0938h-0.641c0.156-0.891 0.203-1.2 0.266-1.41 0.0312-0.156 0.188-0.297 0.359-0.297 0 0 0.188 0 0.328 0.0781-0.297 0.0938-0.312 0.344-0.312 0.375 0 0.156 0.125 0.266 0.281 0.266 0.188 0 0.391-0.156 0.391-0.422 0-0.328-0.328-0.5-0.688-0.5-0.312 0-0.656 0.172-0.844 0.516-0.141 0.266-0.188 0.578-0.344 1.39h-0.547c-0.141 0-0.234 0-0.234 0.156 0 0.0938 0.0938 0.0938 0.219 0.0938h0.516c0 0.0469-0.438 2.55-0.609 3.3-0.0312 0.156-0.156 0.672-0.484 0.672-0.0156 0-0.172 0-0.312-0.0781 0.281-0.0938 0.312-0.344 0.312-0.375 0-0.156-0.125-0.266-0.281-0.266-0.188 0-0.391 0.156-0.391 0.422 0 0.312 0.328 0.5 0.672 0.5 0.438 0 0.75-0.453 0.828-0.609 0.25-0.469 0.422-1.33 0.438-1.41z"/>
  </g>
  <path d="m4.95 26.6v-0.405h9.35v0.405z" color="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width=".1" style="-inkscape-stroke:none"/>
  <g>
   <path d="m8.8 30c-0.0938-0.406-0.406-0.812-1.06-0.812-0.984 0-1.78 0.719-2.03 1.36-0.0469 0.109-0.141 0.391-0.141 0.672 0 0.484 0.375 1.28 1.45 1.28 1.81 0 2.55-2.25 2.55-3.23 0-1.2-0.781-1.88-1.72-1.88-1.14 0-1.45 0.906-1.45 1.11 0 0.0625 0.0469 0.25 0.281 0.25 0.25 0 0.391-0.203 0.391-0.375 0-0.188-0.141-0.25-0.266-0.266 0.344-0.531 0.922-0.531 1.03-0.531 0.531 0 1.14 0.328 1.14 1.33 0 0.297-0.0312 0.547-0.156 1.09zm-1.77 2.28c-0.781 0-0.875-0.594-0.875-0.812 0-0.266 0.188-0.953 0.266-1.12 0.125-0.328 0.547-0.969 1.34-0.969 0.672 0 0.891 0.531 0.891 0.953 0 0.469-0.453 1.95-1.62 1.95z"/>
   <path d="m13.7 29.7c0.0312-0.0938 0.0312-0.109 0.0312-0.156 0-0.141-0.109-0.219-0.234-0.219-0.0781 0-0.203 0.0312-0.281 0.156-0.0312 0.0469-0.0781 0.266-0.109 0.406l-0.156 0.578c-0.0312 0.172-0.25 1.05-0.281 1.12 0 0-0.312 0.609-0.844 0.609-0.484 0-0.484-0.453-0.484-0.578 0-0.375 0.156-0.812 0.375-1.36 0.0781-0.219 0.109-0.297 0.109-0.422 0-0.328-0.281-0.594-0.656-0.594-0.703 0-1.02 0.953-1.02 1.08 0 0.0781 0.0938 0.0781 0.125 0.0781 0.0938 0 0.0938-0.0312 0.125-0.109 0.172-0.578 0.469-0.844 0.75-0.844 0.109 0 0.172 0.0781 0.172 0.234 0 0.172-0.0625 0.312-0.0938 0.406-0.344 0.859-0.406 1.11-0.406 1.42 0 0.109 0 0.438 0.266 0.672 0.219 0.172 0.516 0.203 0.703 0.203 0.281 0 0.531-0.0938 0.75-0.312-0.0781 0.391-0.156 0.688-0.453 1.03-0.188 0.219-0.469 0.438-0.844 0.438-0.0469 0-0.375 0-0.516-0.219 0.375-0.0469 0.375-0.375 0.375-0.391 0-0.219-0.203-0.266-0.266-0.266-0.172 0-0.406 0.141-0.406 0.469 0 0.344 0.328 0.609 0.828 0.609 0.703 0 1.56-0.547 1.78-1.42z"/>
   <path d="m17.9 31.6h-2.33v0.625h2.95v-29.9h-2.95v0.625h2.33z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Here's the fixed SVG in Illustrator

[image]